# How to display Navigation bar when tab bar item clicked

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I m working on Iphone application which is having `UITabBarController` and  `UINavigationController`

I am switching to `UIWebView` in flow of the project before which its all Native

When I switch to webview I am able to hide the Navigation bar

but when I clicked on a tab which brings it to home page I cant see navigation bar unless I select any option and go to next view

I did find out abt tabbar function

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

but I m not getting how to unhide or display the navigation bar again??
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

to set the navigationController's navigationBar to hidden.

If you use this in the other views in viewWillAppear you need to set it to non hidden again

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```